# Java, JSP, Eclipse - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I'm using Eclipse to create a "Dynamic Web Project". And i write some simple code by MVC structure.

My **LoaiBean** class:

```
package bean;
public class LoaiBean {
    private String maLoai;
    private String tenLoai;
    public String getMaLoai() {
        return maLoai;
    }
    public void setMaLoai(String maLoai) {
        this.maLoai = maLoai;
    }
    public String getTenLoai() {
        return tenLoai;
    }
    public void setTenLoai(String tenLoai) {
        this.tenLoai = tenLoai;
    }
    public LoaiBean(String maLoai, String tenLoai) {
        super();
        this.maLoai = maLoai;
        this.tenLoai = tenLoai;
    }
}
```

My **LoaiDao** class:

```
package dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import bean.LoaiBean;
public class LoaiDao {
    private DBConnection dbConnection = null;
    public LoaiDao() {
        super();
        this.dbConnection = new DBConnection("bookdb");
    }
    public LoaiDao(DBConnection dbConnection) {
        super();
        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }
    /**
     * get list of categories
     * @return {@link ArrayList}
     */
    public ArrayList<LoaiBean> getLoai(){
        Connection connection = this.dbConnection.getConnection(true);
        ArrayList<LoaiBean> loais = new ArrayList<LoaiBean>();
        try {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery("select * from loai");
            while(rs.next()) {
                loais.add(new LoaiBean(
                    rs.getString("maloai"),
                    rs.getString("tenloai")
                ));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return loais;
    }
}
```

My **DBConnection** class:

```
package dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class DBConnection {
    private String server = "localhost";
    private String port = "1433";
    private String databaseName = null;
    private String user = "sa";
    private String password = "123";
    private Connection connection = null;
    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }
    public void setServer(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
    public String getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(String port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }
    public void setDatabaseName(String databaseName) {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Connection getConnection(boolean autoConnect) {
        if(autoConnect && this.connection == null) {
            this.connect();
        }
        return connection;
    }
    public void setConnection(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
    public DBConnection(String databaseName) {
        super();
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }
    public void connect() {
        if(this.databaseName == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String st = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+this.server+":"+this.port+";databaseName="+this.databaseName+";user="+this.user+";password="+this.password;
            try {
                this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(st);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void reconnect() {
        this.disconnect();
        this.connect();
    }
    public void disconnect() {
        if(this.connection != null) {
            try {
                this.connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My **LoaiBo** class:

```
package bo;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import bean.LoaiBean;
import dao.LoaiDao;
public class LoaiBo {
    private LoaiDao dao = null;
    public LoaiDao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }
    public void setDao(LoaiDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    public LoaiBo() {
        super();
        this.dao = new LoaiDao();
    }
    public LoaiBo(LoaiDao dao) {
        super();
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    public ArrayList<LoaiBean> getLoai(){
        return this.dao.getLoai();
    }
}
```

And My JSP file **tc.jsp**:

```
<%@page import="bean.LoaiBean"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="bo.LoaiBo"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <%
    LoaiBo bo = new LoaiBo();
    ArrayList<LoaiBean> loais = bo.getLoai(); // error is showed here
    %>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <% for (LoaiBean loaiBean : loais) { %>
                <li class="list-group-item"><%= loaiBean.getMaLoai()  %></li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>       
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run file tc.jsp above, the error is appear:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mupaC.png)

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/tc.jsp] at line [17]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/tc.jsp] at line [17]

14: <body>
15:     <%
16:     LoaiBo bo = new LoaiBo();
17:     ArrayList<LoaiBean> loais = bo.getLoai();
18:     %>
19:     <div class="row justify-content-center">
20:         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:625)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:514)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    dao.LoaiDao.getLoai(LoaiDao.java:39)
    bo.LoaiBo.getLoai(LoaiBo.java:40)
    org.apache.jsp.tc_jsp._jspService(tc_jsp.java:140)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

These function run normally when i test by a java core class with main function, but not run in jsp file.

I'm using eclipse, tomcat 9, java 8.

I don't know how to fix this problem. I hope people guys will help me. Thank you.

Comment: add a debug inside LoaiBo.java I think there is a problem with this.dao.getLoai()

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried to test that function, it run normally. https://i.imgur.com/LS6L4N6.png

Comment: welcome, please approve if your issue resolved

Comment: The jsp file still not run, i've just tested the function run normally.

Comment: Hi. Could you please remove your error image and paste it as code? If someone experiences the same error as you they won't be able to google the problem as Google doesn't read image text :)

Comment: yes, i've edited the post

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below get the list object from LoaiDao.class

```
<%
    LoaiDao loaiDao = new LoaiDao();
    ArrayList<LoaiBean> loais = loaiDao.getLoai(); 
%>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i tried to get list from LoaiDao, but it still the same error. https://i.imgur.com/lGyrvij.png